# ASP.NET Core MVC and Entity Framework output param not returning when calling stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a procedure which returns the identity of the record added. I am using Entity Framework to call the procedure and retrieve the value, but it is always  0.

This is the code - can you figure out why it is not returning the identity value?

C# Entity Framework domain code:

```
var cNumber = new SqlParameter("CNumber", acctSl.cNumber);
var fId = new SqlParameter("FId", acctSl.FId);
var splAmt = new SqlParameter("SplAmt", acctSl.SplAmt);
var frDt = new SqlParameter("FrDt", acctSl.FrDate);
var toDt = new SqlParameter("ToDt", acctSl.ToDate);
var user = new SqlParameter("User", acctSl.User);

var id = new SqlParameter("Id", "")
            {
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar
            };

var sql = "EXECUTE [dbo].[InsertAcctSpl] @CNumber, @FID, @SplAmt, @FrDt, @ToDt, @User, @Id OUTPUT";
var result = DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql, cNumber, fId, splAmt, frDt, toDt, user, id);

int rowsAffected;
var yourOutput = Convert.ToInt32(id.Value);

if (result > 0)
{
    acctSl.AcctId = yourOutput;
}
else
{
    acctSl.AcctId = 0;
}
```

SQL Server procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertAccountsSpend]
    @CNumber varchar(15),
    @FId bigint,
    @SplAmt money,
    @FrDt date,
    @ToDt date,
    @User bigint,
    @Id bigint OUTPUT
AS
    INSERT INTO AcctSpend (CNmbr, FID, SplAmt, FrDt, ToDt, 
                           Cr8Dt, Cr8User_ID, UpdtDt, UpdtUser_ID)
    VALUES (@CNumber, @FId, @splAmt, @FroDt,@ ToDt,
            GETDATE(), @User, GETDATE(), @User)
    
    SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    RETURN @id
```

Comment: Can you manually check the database to see if the row is being created? It may be returning `0` because it is not executing the stored procedure as expected.

Comment: yes I see the row being created

Comment: var yourOutput = Convert.ToInt32(id.Value); -- returns 1 which seems to be number of rows added not the id of the inserted row

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be with this section of your code:

```
int rowsAffected;
var yourOutput = Convert.ToInt32(id.Value);

if (rowsAffected > 0)
{
    acctSl.AcctId = yourOutput;
}
else
{
    acctSl.AcctId = 0;
}
```

You are basing your `if-else` logic off of the `rowsAffected` variable, but that variable is never assigned the value from your stored procedures output. Since `rowsAffected` is declared as an `int` type variable, it cannot be `null`, so it is automatically set to `0`.

To get the actual value for `rowsAffected` you will need to utilize the data returned in your `result` variable that you have declared here:

```
var result = DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql, cNumber, fId, splAmt, frDt, toDt, user, id);
```

**EDIT**

It appears that the syntax around your `id` SQL parameter object is incorrect. Try creating this object in the following manner:

```
var id = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "Id",
    DbType = System.Data.DbType.String,
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
};
```

Comment: I updated my code above even when I do that                                                                  var yourOutput = Convert.ToInt32(id.Value);    -- this is being returned as 1                                     which is not correct

Comment: I've just updated my answer with the proper syntax for creating a SQP parameter object.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the data type it needed be long

```
var id = new SqlParameter("Id", "")
            {
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
                **SqlDbType = SqlDbType.BigInt**
            };
```